# Is the string property immutable in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf

My model:

```
sealed class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
// INotifyPropertyChanged notifies the View of property changes, so that Bindings are updated.
```

sealed class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private User user;

```
public string FirstName { 
    get {return user.FirstName;} 
    set {
        if(user.FirstName != value) {
            user.FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChange("FirstName");
            // If the first name has changed, the FullName property needs to be udpated as well.
            OnPropertyChange("FullName");
        }
    }
}

public string LastName {
    get { return user.LastName; }
    set {
        if (user.LastName != value) {
            user.LastName = value;
            OnPropertyChange("LastName");
            // If the first name has changed, the FullName property needs to be udpated as well.
            OnPropertyChange("FullName");
        }
    }
}

// This property is an example of how model properties can be presented differently to the View.
// In this case, we transform the birth date to the user's age, which is read only.
public int Age { 
    get {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        int age = today.Year - user.BirthDate.Year;
        if (user.BirthDate > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
        return age;
    }
}

// This property is just for display purposes and is a composition of existing data.
public string FullName {
    get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}

public MyViewModel() {
    user = new User {
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Doe",
        BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30)
    };
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName) {
    if(PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

Then in xaml we use binding:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="4" Text="{Binding FullName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>

<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4" Content="First Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
<!-- UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged makes sure that changes in the TextBoxes are immediately applied to the model. -->
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4" Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200"/>

  <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4" Content="Last Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4" Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="200"/>

   <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="4" Content="Age:" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="4" Text="{Binding Age}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MyViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        // The DataContext serves as the starting point of Binding Paths
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

My question is that for binding. For example, if `FirstName` is changed, the view is changed as well. We know string in C# is immutable, when the value changes a new object is created. But in WPF binding, if `FirstName` is changed, is a new FirstName object created? I assume it is NO since we use binding to hold the value in one object. So does `OnPropertyChange` remove the immutable internally?

Comment: string is immutable

Comment: Strings are immutable in c#. There are more things going on than a "new object is created". But the concept is the same. What is your exact concern? Performance?

Comment: I meant this code `Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`, when FirstName is changes, does the code create new FirstName object in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVVM, you bind to Properties (not to the backing members).

When you change a Property, like a `string`, then you technically place a new object behind the class member (i.e. the backing instance of a property).

`OnPropertyChanged` tells that to the View, so it calls the Property Getter (not the string instance) again, getting a the new instance etc...

If you would not, the View would hold and display a reference to the old string, which is no longer used by your Viewmodel

Then, we have

`ObservableCollections` and `Observable` types, that can do this notification automatically, because they are mutable, meaning they stay the same instance, while only their content changes.

Most commonly, ObservableCollections are used, to notify the View, that it contents has changed (while the collection instance stayed the same). (element added, removed..)

In that case, you dont need to Notify, because the View has registered to that event.

If you would assign a new instance to an observableCollection member, the view would also not update correctly without Propertychanged, because the original instance of the collection would no longer change.

Comment: So the backing instance of a property is immutable?

Comment: depending on the type of the backing member.
if the backing member is a string, or any other value object, it is immutable.
if it is i.e observablecollection, it IS mutable

Answer (score 2):

No, `FirstName` is not reassigned or mutated. It is a reference to a backing `string` that is reassigned.

When you have an [auto-implemented property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties):

```cs
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

It is compiled ([roughly](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKAKwAIAxAe3OIG8Dj7j0BmR7ABjKgCcBnAFwByEMAFMaxAOYi+AbmI9pcgL4ElQA==)) into:

```cs
private string _firstName;
public string FirstName 
{
    get => _firstName;
    set => _firstName = value;
}
```

As you can see, assigning a value to `FirstName` passes the value as an argument to the `setter` for `FirstName` which reassigns `_firstName` (the private backing field). `FirstName` is never changed.

This is also why `INotifyProperyChanged` is required. Because the binding is on `FirstName` and `FirstName` never changes, the framework needs a way to tell when the value referenced by `FirstName` changes.

Comment: So `_firstName (the private backing field)` is immutable?

Comment: Correct. All `string`s are immutable. `_firstName` is reassigned whenever you change its value.

Comment: I am okay for down voting since I learnt something. One more follow question, since _firstName is reassigned whenever you change its value. How about the old string, was that garbage collected yet? Otherwise if the value is changed very often and the objects are created again and again, the memory could blow up.

Comment: I did not downvote your question. Yes, reassigning the value of `_firstName` removes the reference to the memory holding the original value and the GC will eventually deallocate it or otherwise return it to the memory pool. You don't have to worry about auto-implemented properties causing memory leaks.